# Change minimize window animation in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

Is there any way to change minimize window animation in Ubuntu.
I want to set minimize animation like Mac OS.

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: This Question has been answered here on ask-Ubuntu : [LinK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788884/change-window-animations-in-ubuntu-16-04-without-additional-tools)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `compizconfig-settings-manager` to change windows minimize animations in Ubuntu.

**Installation :**

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Or install using Ubuntu Software center :

[image: Install via the software center]

---

**Usage :**

Launch `compizconfig-settings-manager`, go in "**Effects**" > "**Animations**" > "**Minimize Animation**" tab.

Click on "**Edit**" and simply select the animation you want to use (I am not sure which one is closest to Mac OS animation. I let you test) :

[image: Compizconfig manager screenshot]

You can also change the duration of the animation.