# Change window animations in Ubuntu 16.04 without additional tools

Tags: unity, 16.04

How can I change the window animations (minimize and restore) in Ubuntu 16.04 using command line only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the following commands to change the minimize and restore/unminimize animation, respectively:

```
gsettings set org.compiz.animation:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/animation/ minimize-effects [\'animation:NEWANIMATION\']
gsettings set org.compiz.animation:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/animation/ unminimize-effects [\'animation:NEWANIMATION\']
```

And replace `NEWANIMATION` by one of the following strings:

```
None
Random
Curved Fold
Fade
Glide 1
Glide 2
Horizontal Folds
Magic Lamp
Magic Lamp Wavy
Sidekick
Zoom
```

It seems like an invalid string is equivalent to `None`. The default value for `minimize-effects` is `Zoom`, for `unminimize-effects` it's `Glide 2`.

I extracted this information from the file [`UnityTweakTool/section/windowmanager.py`](https://github.com/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool/blob/master/UnityTweakTool/section/windowmanager.py#L81) from the Unity Tweak Tool source code.